# Removing irrelevant information of online articles

Tags: nlp, text-classification, data-cleaning

I am doing text classification to detect political leaning in online news article. The problem is that the articles are very noisy with media attributes  such as media tag line, articles copyright, information of publication, author/reporter names, related-article links, etc, and there is no separator between the main information and the noise (html tags were already removed).
I've read several papers about how to clean irrelevant information from crawled online articles; however, all of them was doing the cleaning process in collection stage by using HTML tag. My research is purely NLP so it's out of my project's scope.

I've studied about removing stopwords based on IDF and Information gain, also by using outlier detection techniques (distance-based, clustering based) . But I don't think they can work in my case.
Any suggestions how to automatically remove those irrelevant contents of news articles?
Thank you for any comments and answers.

Comment: can you post some example articles as well

Comment: Hey @dede, Have you solved this?

Comment: Yeah. I used k-means clustering. I split the text per line first, then clustered the lines. the k-means clusters the similar/repeated lines into the same clusters and unique line into another cluster.